# Joining 3 dataframes into a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, nested, databricks

I have 3 dataframes as follows:

1. Product with columns: product_no, product_name, product_start_date, product_end_date, product_price
2. Part with columns: product_no, part_registration_no, part_name, part_make, part_color
3. Supplier with columns: product_no, part_registration_no, supplier_name, cost

Each Product may have more than 1 Part and each Part may have more than 1 Supplier.
The key that links Product to Part is **product_no** while the key to link Supplier to Part is **part_registration_no**.

I will need to join these 3 dataframes and convert it into dictionary / json in the following format prescribed by the API (i have no control over the format).

[image]
{
"product_no": XXX,
"product_name": XXX,
"product_start_date": XXX,
"product_end_date": XXX,
"product_price": XXX,
"part_data": [
{
"part_registration_no": XXX,
"part_name": XXX,
"part_make": XXX,
"part_color": XXX,
"supplier_data":[
{
"supplier_name":XXX,
"cost": XXX,
}
]
}
]
}

I have joined the dataframes using pd.merge but i am not sure how to create the dictionary.
Attempted groupby to no avail.
Could anyone please provide some direction on how this can be done?
Doing this in Databricks if this info is of any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## df3 to json

```
df3['supplier_data'] = df3.apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)
df3 = df3.drop(['supplier_name', 'cost'], axis=1)
```

## merge df3 to df2

```
df32 = df2.merge(df3, how='inner', on='product_no')
```

## df2 to json

```
df2['part_data'] = df2.apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)
df2 = df2.drop(['part_registration_no', 'part_name', 'part_make', 'part_color', 'supplier_data'], axis=1)
```

## merge df2 to df1

```
df21 = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='product_no')
```

## df final

```
df_final = df21.to_json()
```

note: change inner join to what you need